# Form closing immediately

Tags: winforms

```
    Dim details As New frmDetails(ID, JobID, True)
    details.ShowDialog()
```

The form flashes open and immediately closes.  If I use *Show*() rather than *ShowDialog*() it stays open and look fine.  Here are some things I've checked:

- Breaking in **FormClosing** shows only

> > > > System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnFormClosing 
> > > >           System.Windows.Forms.Form.CheckCloseDialog
> > > >           System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponent.FContinueMessageLoop 
> > > >           System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop
> > > >           System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner
> > > >           System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop
> > > >           System.Windows.Forms.Application.RunDialog
> > > >
> > > > System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog

between the *ShowDialog* and the **FormClosing**.

- **CloseReason** is "None"
- **Load** runs to the end, as does **VisibleChanged** (though **Activated** never gets called).
- There's no sign of any Exceptions being thrown.
- Intellitrace doesn't show anything going on.
- After the form closes, the **DialogResult** is "Cancel" (There's no reference to DialogResult in the form or its Designer)
- I'm not doing any explicit threading

I'd appreciate any suggestions either as to what's going on or how to go about finding out.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have control events triggered during Form_Load (Text_Changed, Validating etc). Could be one of these events that closes the form? (Still doesn't explain why the Form.Show works)

Comment: Are you using a custom contructor for this form?

Comment: It's a complicated for and lots of things are going on, but when I ran using IntelliTrace I saw only one event generated during the Load, and that event doesn't call Close() and anyway I took that code out and the problem remained.  Also, I found all the calls to Close() in the code and set breakpoints on them, but none was ever reached.  And as you say, it doesn't explain Show().  I do have custom c-tors, but I'm not sure what difference those would make:  They're called before Load and for Show() as well.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I was setting the `DialogResult` property on the load event to `Cancel`, and that was causing the dialog to close immediately after Load. I've set it to the default None and now I only set it to other value on the `Click` event of a button when I really need to close it.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this will probably do nobody any good, but here's how I solved the problem:

There was a line in the **Load** method that read

```
Me.Text = ""
```

I have no idea what it was doing there (this isn't my code, thank goodness), especially since the value gets set again later on, but taking that line out stopped the form from mysteriously closing.  Go figure.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. In my case it was due to not specifying the parent window on the ShowDialog(). The dialog associated with the window that was topmost, which happened to be a combobox drop-down that was going away.

In my case, I changed the ShowDialog() call to use my application's main window as the parent, and problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Been debugging for couple of hours with the same problem. In my case the likely reason was that the parent form has setting `ShowInTaskbar = false` in `Load` event, while my form had this set to true in the designer. For some reason this caused the dialog result to be set to `Cancel` during initialization.

Comment: Same here. 2 days debugging...